# L-System in Mathematica

Tags: recursion, fractals

Here is some *Maple* code for drawing an [*L-System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system):

```maple
  with(Fractals:-LSystem)
  cons := ["A" = "draw:1", "+" = "turn:-90", "B" = "turn:90"]
  state, rules := "A", ["A" = "AB+BA+B", "B" = "B+AAB"]
  newstate1 := Iterate(state, rules, 7)

  LSystemPlot(newstate1, cons)
```

[image: L-system]

How can I make the same graphic using *Mathematica*?

I tried the first few steps:

```
SubstitutionSystem[{"A" -> "AB+BA+B", "B" -> "B+AAB"}, "A", {3}]
```

> ```
> {"AB+BA+BB+AAB+B+AABAB+BA+B+B+AAB"}
> ```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
str = First@
   SubstitutionSystem[{"A" -> "AB+BA+B", "B" -> "B+AAB"}, "A", {7}];

asc = <|"A" -> {1, 0}, "B" -> {0, Pi/2}, "+" -> {0, -Pi/2}|>;
```

Here `{1,0}` means go forward 1 step and turn 0 radians.  The turtle graphics substitute in Mathematica is [`AnglePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html).

```
Graphics[
 Line@AnglePath@Lookup[asc, Characters[str]]
]
```

---

Thanks to @Pillsy, a shorter and faster way is

```
StringCases[str, {"A" -> {1, 0}, "B" -> {0, Pi/2}, "+" -> {0, -Pi/2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. Cool knowledge of recent functions.

Comment: Sweet. You can also generate the angle path steps in a single step using `StringCases`.

Comment: @Vitaliy Actually I did not know `SubstitutionSystem`. I am happy to have learned something new.

Comment: @Pillsy Indeed.  It's faster too.  Somehow I always thought of `StringCases` as a strictly string related function, and it simply did not occur to me to use it this way.