# A box structure with a depth exceeding the maximum allowed depth was encountered

Tags: graphics, warning-messages, fractals, broken-code

I am trying to perform the task in Mark McClure's article [Parametric L-Systems and borderline fractals](https://www.marksmath.org/scholarship/PLSystemsPP.pdf). I have copied his opening code on the first three pages:

```
axiom = {F[1], r[-2 π/3], F[1], r[-2 π/3], F[1]};
KochRule = F[x_] :> {F[x/3], r[π/3], F[x/3], r[-2 π/3], F[x/3], r[π/3], F[x/3]};
instructions = Flatten[Nest[# /. KochRule &, axiom, 5]];
lines = {};
lastpt = {0, 0};
dir = {1, 0};
rotate[θ_] := N[{  {Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]},  {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}];
turtleInterpretation = {
   F[x_] :> (lines = {Line[{lastpt, lastpt += x dir}], lines}),
   r[t_] :> (dir = rotate[t].dir;)};
instructions /. turtleInterpretation;
Show[Graphics[lines],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I am using Mathematica 11.1.1 on a MacBook Pro with Sierra OS X. When I evaluated the cell, I got a beep and the following image.

[image]

I went to the Help menu and selected "Why the Beep" and got the message

> A box structure with a depth exceeding the maximum allowed depth was encountered.

Any suggestions?

**Update:** I thought I'd share another technique I discovered by examining [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143214/l-system-in-mathematica):

```
str = First@SubstitutionSystem[{"F" -> "F-F++F-F"}, "F++F++F", {6}];
Graphics[Line[
  AnglePath[
   StringCases[
    str, {"F" -> {1, 0}, "+" -> {0, Pi/3}, "-" -> {0, -Pi/3}}]]]]
```

Gave this image:

[image]

Comment: With *Mathematica* 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64 I do not get the beep and error message, but the line isn't rendered completely (as in the question).

Answer (score 7):

Don't know how to alter the limit but the problem comes from:

```
lines = {Line[{lastpt, lastpt += x dir}], lines}
```

as it makes `lines` gain one level for each `F` occurence.

It is not "strange" though, the reason are linked lists which are faster approach of accumulating data

> [...] The idiom lines = {newLine, lines} creates a deeply nested structure but was the old school way to get around the AppendTo [...]
>
> - Mark McClure

See also point 3.3: [Performance tuning in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29351/5478)

The quick fix is:

```
Show[Graphics[lines // Flatten], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: The package was written a *long* time ago and I'm sure I would do a lot differently now. The idiom `lines = {newLine, lines}` creates a deeply nested structure but was the old school way to get around the `AppendTo` approach of dynamically building up a list which is (as I'm sure you know) slow since it rewrites the list with each step.

Comment: @MarkMcClure yep, planned to elaborate on that but it was late yesterday. Done now, also included part of your comment, thanks.

Comment: @Kuba were you able to dig up what setting causes the beep? Initially I assumed it was a `$RecursionLimit` issue as the `Depth` of the `lines` is 3000+ which is greater than the default `$RecursionLimit`. But that didn't fix it and neither did mucking about with ``BoxForm`RecursionLimit`` (although I assume that's an option -- to what I don't know though).

Comment: @MB1965 `$RecursionLimit` is a kernel feature but the beed happens when rendering takes place I tried ``Names["F*`*imit*"]`` but to no avail so I assumed it is somewhere in those FE/system options I don't have time to dig now :)

Comment: @Kuba good to know. I'd assumed there might be some kernel call in the box formatting, but maybe not. Another failed candidate I found was `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "BoxFormattingRecursionLimit"]`.

Answer (score 3):

Kuba already explained this issue well.  This is merely a complementary post.  To avoid the problem an alternative to `Flatten` is collecting your results differently.  Also you do not need to draw every line segment separately, you can put all the points in a single `Line` expression.

For example you could use:

```
turtleInterpretation = {F[x_] :> Sow[x dir], r[t_] :> (dir = rotate[t].dir;)};
raw = Reap[instructions /. turtleInterpretation][[2, 1]];
pts = Accumulate[Prepend[raw, {0, 0}]];

Show[Graphics[Line[pts]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

Or we could trivialize the `F` expressions and write something like:

```
axiom = {F, r[-2 π/3], F, r[-2 π/3], F};
KochRule = F -> Sequence[F, r[π/3], F, r[-2 π/3], F, r[π/3], F];
iter = 6;
instructions = Nest[# /. KochRule &, axiom, iter];

raw = FoldList[#2.# &, {1, 0}, RotationMatrix @@@ N @ instructions[[2 ;; ;; 2]]];
pts = Accumulate[raw] (1/3)^iter;
AppendTo[pts, First@pts];

Show[Graphics[Line[pts]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```